# Varying edge thickness

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, graphs, dimensions

A couple of months back, I had asked a question regarding an elegant way of drawing a somewhat sophisticated graph. Thanks to the community I received tremendous help. To avoid repeating the whole thing, here's the link of the mentioned thread:

[Typesetting digraph with weighted edges, varying vertex size, multiple lines in vertex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109514/typesetting-digraph-with-weighted-edges-varying-vertex-size-multiple-lines-in)

As you may see, in this weighted-digraph the edges have weights as well. My question is, how may I enhance the solution proposed by Gonzalo Medina so that the edges are visually distinguishable as well wrt. their weights?

For instance, as you might see in the original graph (d,c) has a weight of 0.9 whereas (e,a) has 0.1 thus I would like to draw the former much thicker than the latter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `line width` option of the `\draw` command and, if you want, you can do the same with the node contours using the same option of the `\node` command.

In the following code I have used as `line width` value in `pt` two times your "wwight". But in this way most lines seems equal so play with the `line width` value to have the desired effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{255,255,150}

\newcommand\mytext[3][\scriptsize]{#2\\#1 #3}
\newcommand\mynode[4][]{%
  \node[mynode,#1,text width=\the\dimexpr#2cm*3] (#3) {\mytext{#3}{#2 #4}}; 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=2cm,
mynode/.style={
  circle,
  draw,
  fill=myyellow,
  align=center}
]
\mynode[line width=1.34pt]{0.67}{d}{(130/61)}
\mynode[below=of d,line width=0.9pt]{0.45}{c}{(130/61)}
\mynode[below=of c,line width=1.0pt]{0.50}{a}{(130/61)} 
\mynode[left=of a,line width=1.34pt]{0.67}{b}{(130/61)} 
\mynode[right=of c,line width=1.9pt]{0.95}{e}{(130/61)}
\draw[->,line width=1.8pt] 
  (d) -- node[rotate=90,below] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.9}{(72/8)}} (c); 
\draw[->,line width=1.6pt] 
  (c) -- node[rotate=90,below] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.8}{(44/11)}} (a);
\draw[->,line width=1.7pt] 
  (d) -- node[sloped,below] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.85}{(68/12)}} (b); 
\draw[->,line width=0.2pt] 
  (e) -- node[sloped,below] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.1}{(4/36)}} (a); 
\draw[->,line width=1.5pt] 
  (b) to[bend left] node[above] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.75}{(56/24)}} (a); 
\draw[->,line width=1.8pt] 
  (a) to[bend left] node[below] {\mytext[\normalsize]{0.9}{(63/7)}} (b); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]