# Formatting node and edge labels in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, how to format node and edge label (node and edge weight)? For example, how to make the edge weight in bold?

Comment: Please give an MWE which shows what you have. You can set any text as `\textbf{Text}`

Comment: Did you mean something like this? [Varying edge thickness](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132606/4778)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of two nodes (n1 with label A, and n2 with label B) with a bold edge in between and with a bold edge weight. As LaRiFaRi has suggested in the comments you can use `\textbf` to get bold text. If you want bold math you should use `\bm` from the `bm` package.

Nodes and edges are formatted by specifying options between square brackets (circle, draw, thick, ...). I suggest you take a look at section 17 "Nodes and Edges" of the [TikZ and PGF manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to get familiar with possible options

Labels (such as edge weights) are formatted the same way as normal text (`\textbf`, ...) or math (`\bm`, ...)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[circle,draw] (n1) at (0,0) {A};
        \node[circle,draw] (n2) at (5,0) {B};

        \draw (n1) edge[thick] node[above]{$\bm{w_1}$} (n2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP is mentioning a literal edge such as `\path (n1) edge[thick] (n2);`

Comment: @percusse You might be right. Though his formatting example (bold edge weight) isn't affected by this, I'll edit anyway.